# grpc import bug on arm linux system - ImportError: cannot import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython'

Tags: python, cython, grpc, grpc-python

I'm trying to get a grpc (grpcio) service to run on an armv7 system running linux (openembedded poky).
As our it-dep. doesn't allow us to connect our dev boards to our network/internet I'm ushin wheels to install grpcio (+six as it depends on it). The installation works fine, but whenever I try to import the lib in python it fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/root/rp_py_sw/sc_rp_sw.py", line 6, in <module>
    import grpc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from grpc._cython import cygrpc as _cygrpc
ImportError: cannot import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython' (/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_cython/__init__.py)
```

This is with py3.8.5
Using py 3.6 it worked fine.

Before I used py36 as there where no arm builds for >3.6 for some time. Now that there are some newer builds I thought about switching to py3.8 or 3.9 but for some reason it fails with the error above.

I should mention that I generate the os using yocto, which also builds and includes py3.8.5.
py3.6 (the working one) was build by myself. Has anyone an idea why it won't work after the update, is there something wrong/missing in yoctos py3.8.5?

Comment: Probably related: [github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/26094](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/26094)

Comment: Looks the same, thanks so I'm not the only one. Why didn't I see that when I asked google...

Answer (score 1):

This two commands would help:
(1)pip install grpcio
(2)pip install cygrpc